# Alphabet Letters to Numbers R without Match

Tags: r, type-conversion

I am trying to get a function which inputs a specific letter (like "a" or "b") and outputs the position it is in alphabet (1 and 2). I am not allowed to use the match function and inputs like "abc" and "2" should yield NULL.

So far I have:

```
char2int = function(a)

    {
    return(grep(x, letters))
    }

char2int("b")
```

and I'm getting integer(0).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If your function argument is 'a' then why is pattern in grep 'x'.  BTW is the restriction only for `match` or will it extends to other functions?

Comment: lmfao oh my god. im an idiot

Answer (score 1):

This should work

`l.func <- function(x) { which(tolower(x)==letters) }`